# Diffeomorphism on $S^2$ to $S^2$ with at least two fixed points

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, fixed-point-theorems, spheres

> Let $f:S^2\to S^2$ diffeomorphism orientation-preserving such that for
>   every fixed point of $f$, $1$ is not an eigenvalue of $df_p$. Then $f$
>   admits at least two fixed points.

I'd to construct a concrete example of a function as above. Do you know any?

Comment: What about a nontrivial rotation?

Comment: @PseudoNeo Doesn't a rotation of $S^2$ have two fixed points, on each pole of the rotational axis?

Comment: You want to use a stronger version of the Lefschetz fixed point theorem, one for which the Lefschetz number gives an actual count of fixed points.

Comment: I've already proved the result. I need to build an example now.

Comment: Do you mean you want to have examples with more than 2 fixed points? As for constructing examples, think about integrating vector fields X (zeroes of X are the fixed points). If you do not know how to construct vector fields, try to construct functions $S^2\to R$ and then taking their gradients. Can you construct a function with exactly 4 nondegenerate critical points?